# 'ngCordovaOauth' not working in ionic unknown provider: $cordovaOauthprovider <- $cordovaOauth

Tags: oauth, ionic-framework, twitter-oauth

I tried to use ngCordovaOauth plugin but it didn't work.
It gives me following error

```
 unknown provider: $cordovaOauthprovider <- $cordovaOauth
```

First I install this plugin

```
bower install ng-cordova-oauth -S
```

Give path in index.html

```
<script src="lib/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>
```

Controller is as follow...

```
.controller('Ctrl',function($scope,$rootScope,XXXService,XXXService,$ionicPopup,$state,md5,$ionicHistory,$ionicLoading,MyServices,$cordovaOauth) {
})
  $cordovaOauth.twitter("XXXX", "CCXXXXX").then(function(result) {
}
```

What else is needed to configure?
I can not run this in mobile device
It gives me provider error
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

you should add ngCordovaOauth to app.js

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ionic', 
    'ngCordovaOauth',
    ...
])
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problems and i solved these with the ng-cordova. ng-cordova comes with oauth.So try to insall the latest version.If you still have problems,
In ng-cordova.js replace all the occurencies of org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser with cordova-plugin-inappbrowser